# ERROR ITMS-90158: URL schemes need to begin with an alphabetic character - Google client ID

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, xcode, google, swift

When trying to Upload to App Store... received the following error:

**ERROR ITMS-90158: "The following URL schemes found in your app are not in the correct format: ... URL schemes need to begin with an alphabetic character"**

The url in question is the Google client ID, that worked well before and doesn't give any error while building or validating archive however, after uploading to App Store, gives the error:

> ERROR ITMS-90158: "The following URL schemes found in your app are not
>   in the correct format:
>   [012345678910-kn4fsmu9sql2rtq6juun2dehji3h0pkr]. URL schemes need to
>   begin with an alphabetic character, and be comprised of alphanumeric
>   characters, the period, the hyphen or the plus sign only. Please see
>   RFC1738 for more detail."

Using Xcode Version 7.3.1 (7D1014) and the error only started to appear recently (around Xcode 8 release date)

Comment: this is the line that causing the error on the App Store 

`GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"`

Comment: I am having same issue while uploading app on app store. Please help me.

App is crashing When I tried to add  GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleus‌​ercontent.com"

Answer (score 2):

I found the problematic URL at: info.plist > URL schemes and reversed it myself. i.e.: com.googleusercontent.apps.xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx

then did a fresh build, all was ok

Answer (score 0):

Found these solutions for the issue, the first didn't work in our case, the second did:

1. Go to: **Project Settings (main screen) > Info > URL Types (n)** and
   check the URL schemes for white-spaces and check is one (or more)
   URLs are reverse domain name format
2. Read this post to programmatically **reverse iOS URL scheme to
   Google Client ID** for iOS:
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39682621/reverse-google-client-id-with-swift/39691166#39691166